# How do I get the text from a context menu?

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity with a list of names (Jacob, Will, Matt, etc.).  I have a contextMenu which gives the user the option to edit or delete the person.  I know how to find the id to perform the edit and delete functionality, but I can't figure out how to get the person's name to be added to the intent extras or to add a toast when a delete occurs.

Here is a snippet of code that I'm using for the context menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        mDbHelper.deletePerson(info.id);
        fillData();
        return true;
    case EDIT_ID:
        Cursor c = mCursor;
        c.moveToPosition(info.position);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonEdit.class);
        i.putExtra("_id", info.id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Macarse.  I somehow stumbled across the answer to my own question.  It seems to be working correctly.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    Cursor c = mCursor;
    c.moveToPosition(info.position);
    Long id = info.id;
    String person = mCursor.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("person"));

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        Toast.makeText(People.this, person + " has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDbHelper.deletePerson(id);
        fillData();
        return true;
    case EDIT_ID:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonEdit.class);
        i.putExtra("_id", id);
        i.putExtra("person", person);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste from my code:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

try {
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
    // Do something here.
}

Person person = (Person) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
```

`getListAdapter()` is for Activities that extends from `ListActivity`. If you are not using it, get the `ListView` and afterwards the adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I am still missing something.  I am populating the list adapter with a SQLite query.  I do not have a person object to instantiate.

The first few lines of my EDIT_ID functionality show my attempt at getting the person's name from the SQLite database.  I know I am missing quite a bit.